# Rendering image positions different in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to render the images, it comes out perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but is having issues in Safari(v 7.0.3). In Safari, image shifts to bottom right, while I want the image to be at the bottom center.

This is my css

```
.circular {
  /*margin: 10px 30px 0px 30px;*/
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom:-400px;
  left:93%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

HTML :

```
<section class="module parallax parallax-1">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="circular" vertical-align:middle; text-align:center><img src="images/index/yoyo.png" width=120px height=120px></div>
              <div class="social_tags" vertical-align:middle; >
                <a href="https://github.com/yoyo"><img src="images/index/github.png" width=40px height=40px></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yoyo"><img src="images/index/facebook.png" width=40px height=40px></a>
                <a href="mailto:yoyo@gmail.com?Subject=Hello" ><img src="images/index/gmail.png" width=40px  height=40px></a>
                <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/yoyo"><img src="images/index/linkedin.png" width=40px height=40px></a>
              </div>
            </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari? Have you tried using the `-webkit-` prefix for the `transform` property? When you say it "is having issues", can you elaborate on what issues you are seeing?

Comment: @Quantastical: Edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues with your html.
I fixed them in this fiddle and it works the same in chrome as in safari: https://jsfiddle.net/msq0eqch/3/

This is the corrected html code:
(You had your style without style="" etc.)

```
<section class="module parallax parallax-1">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="circular" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center"><img src="images/index/yoyo.png" width="120px" height="120px"></div>
              <div class="social_tags" style="vertical-align:middle;" >
                <a href="https://github.com/yoyo"><img src="images/index/github.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yoyo"><img src="images/index/facebook.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
                <a href="mailto:yoyo@gmail.com?Subject=Hello" ><img src="images/index/gmail" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
                <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/yoyo"><img src="images/index/linkedin.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
 </section>
```

Also add  `-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);` to your css.

Comment: It works for Chrome and Safari but not for Firefox. In Firefox the image shift towards right.

Comment: also add `-moz-transform:translateX(-50%);`

Comment: That did it. Thanks :)